# "image_mime_type must be set" when posting an image on the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, uploader

When I try to insert an image in my post, this message appears at the top of the SE app:

> image_mime_type must be set

What does it mean and why does that message appear?

- SE version: 1.0.85
- Android Marshmallow
- MiUi 7

I used the default MiUi gallery.

Comment: May I know what app did you choose as the image chooser? (e.g. Gallery, Google Photo, Google Drive, etc).

Comment: @AndrewT. Done!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: @cullub nope, and the bug is still alive.

Comment: This seems to have [happened again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295962/how-to-add-images-to-my-se-questions).

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.93.

We now assume `image/jpeg` for images where we can't detect a mime-type, and since the error blocking you was just from the API's input validation side, not from the actual image uploader, that fixes it!

Answer (score 3):

### Background:

I tested it on Android Lollipop (version 5.0.2) and Stack Exchange app version 1.0.92

### Steps to recreate the scenario:

I tried to upload a `.png` file and it was uploaded without an issue. Renaming it to a `.jpg` or `.jpeg` file also didn't cause a problem.

However if, for example, I've a file which is named `mypetdog.jpg` and I rename it to just `mypetdog` (without any filename extension) and then try to upload it, I get a red banner at the top which says **image_mime_type must be set**.

### Possible issue and fix:

The image you're trying to upload is perhaps missing an extension. Try adding a filename extension to your image, which basically means to change `mypetdog` to `mypetdog.jpg` or something equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much for the repro step!