# "Answer already accepted", but the checkmark is white

Tags: bug, android-app

*NOTE: I don't have screenshots of this  because a bug of the SE doesn't let me upload photos ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279097/314960))*

This happened to me today when I was accepting an answer. When I tapped on the checkmark, it didn't appeared as green, it appeared as white when the answer was accepted.

*Android Marshmallow, MiUi 7 6.4.14 Beta, Xiaomi Mi3, SE version: Latest*

Comment: Doesn't let upload photos? What?.. At least you could *make* a screenshot.

Comment: @nicael http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279097/314960

Comment: @spund So what? What is the problem to post with the site?

Comment: @nicael the message ' "image_mime_type must be set ' appears every time I try to upload a photo

Comment: With the site, I mean. Not with the app.

Comment: @nicael I can't upload photos that can clarify the content of the post.

Comment: @spund3 I believe nicael means, why don't you try uploading the screenshots from the mobile version of the site, as in by navigating to it on your mobile browser rather than through the app.

Comment: @Kendra because I prefer doing it from the app because its more fast to use than web.

Comment: Yes, but if it's impeding you from showing us a screenshot of the bug, it might be useful to switch to the mobile site long enough to upload the image. I suppose you don't have to, but it would make the issue much clearer.

Comment: @Kendra I think not even the bug report itself specifies clearly what's the problem.

Comment: Or, y'know, use a real computer.

Comment: You can upload to imgur then post a link