# How to add images to my SE questions

Tags: bug, android-app, images, uploader

How can I add images taken from my device (an Android phone) to my questions on Stack Exchange? Whenever I try to upload one it says **image_mime_type must be set**.
I haven't learned JS, so I don't understand this error. Please tell me what I can do.

Comment: I believe you need at least 10 reputation to add an image.

Comment: @Journeyman I meant  my android phone